# Extend iPhoto to post pictures to a different web service?

Tags: cocoa, macos, iphoto

Currently iPhoto lets me upload pictures to Facebook and Flickr. 
Is there any way (perhaps write a plugin) to extend this so that I can post photos to a different web service e.g. Picasa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible. If you are looking for a Picasa plugin, though, Google [already has one](http://picasa.google.com/mac_tools.html) (I haven't used it in the current version of iPhoto). If you are looking to develop your plugins, [this article might help](http://cuboidal.org/iphoto-export-plugin/).